# Infopath 2010 cascading dropdown show value when display names are the same

Tags: infopath, infopath2010, cascadingdropdown

I have an InfoPath form where the user is supposed to choose a *type*. To do this, he must first choose a *group*.

I have done this using cascading dropdowns, where the *types* dropdown is filtered depending on the choise of *group*.

So far, all well.

As my data is now, i have 3 groups, one that contain all types that do not belong in any of the other groups. The other two groups are used to distinguish between types that are called the same, but have different IDs. Like so:

G1: Stuff we own:

- Car - id1
- Sofa - id2
- Bed - id3

G2: Stuff she owns:

- Computer -id4
- Bike - id5

G3: Stuff he owns:

- Computer - id6
- Bike - id7

I have set the Display Value to be the title, and the Value to be the ID.

And here is my problem:
When I from the groups choose "Stuff he owns", and choose type "Computer", the display show "id4" when the dropdown is collapsed again.

If i change all G3 types to have diaplay name different from those in G2, it works as it should.

However, I am not at liberty to change my real data.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your filter. Are you using a lookup list? IF yes, the group should have proper mapping with the types so when you select the group, the corresponding types will show.

GROUP    -- TYPES    -- ID
We own   -- Car      -- 1
We own   -- Sofa     -- 2
We own   -- Bed      -- 3
She owns -- Computer -- 4
She owns -- Bike     -- 5
He owns  -- Computer -- 6
He owns  -- Bike     -- 7

On your filter, it should have Group name = GROUP, so it will only show the TYPES on your type dropdown based on the GROUP mapping.

Comment: The data that gets stored in the form is correct. If I look at the form contet after choosing He ownes - Computer, it has stored 6. But it display 4 in the form itself after the choice has been made, and the dropdown collapses.

Comment: i see, so the id4 is left when you changed the group from "she owns" to "he owns".

solution is to put a rule on the GROUP dropdown. Condition is none the action is set the TYPE field to blank. It will clear the TYPE field when you change your choice in GROUP dropdown

Comment: No, this happens even when I do the choice as the first thing I do when opening the form. And even if id4 is displayed, the value stored in the form is "id6", which is the correct value.

Comment: ok, try creating a rule that will clear the TYPE dropdown on load to see if it will still appear

Comment: It is only displayed after first choosing a group, and then choosing a type. Default value is blank.

Comment: I think your problem is you are keying off "type" rather than "ID". The form is always returning the FIRST entry it finds of type (ID4), no matter which group you are selecting. You need to be keying off ID instead. You can do this by using filters as Mekalikot as mentioned.

Edit: this is why it works when you change the display names to all be unique